# Test or mock a not-exported function with Jest using TypeScript

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

Is there a way to test not-exported functions with Jest using TypeScript? I've seen SO answers recommending some libraries like `rewire` but it seems they are not really TypeScript compatible yet. The other way would be to export these *private* functions as well, but I think there must be a solution without exporting just for testing purposes.

The setup is the following. There are two functions, one is exported, one is not.

```js
export function publicFunction() {
  privateFunction();
}

function privateFunction() {
  // Whatever it does
}
```

In my unit-tests there are two cases I wish to solve. Testing the `privateFunction` itself and mocking it for `publicFunction` tests.

I am using **ts-jest** to compile the typescript files when testing. The **jest.config.json** looks like

```json
{
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.(t|j)sx?$": "ts-jest"
  },
  "testRegex": "(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.(tsx?)$",
  "moduleFileExtensions": ["ts", "tsx", "js", "jsx", "json", "node"],
  "testEnvironment": "node",
  "globals": {
    "ts-jest": {
      "tsConfig": "test/tsconfig.spec.json"
    }
  }
}
```

I am familiar with `jest.fn()` but I don't know how to overwrite or extract the private function. And an unit-test would be something like

```js
import { publicFunction } from '../src';

describe('publicFunction', () => {
  it('should call "privateFunction" once', () => {
    // Overwrite privateFunction with jest.fn();

    publicFunction();

    expect(...).toHaveBeenCalled(1);
  });
});
```

Or to test the private function, for which importing it is not possible.

```
import { privateFunction } from '../src/index'

describe('privateFunction', () => {
  it(...
});
```

Any ideas or suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For testing non-exported functions with JEST and Typescript I have used Rewire. With little problem that we have to provide rewire a path of the TS build folder and not the .ts file path.

Following is my directory structure:

```
app
|---dist
    |---controllers
        |---api.js
    src
    |---controllers
        |---api.ts
        |---api.spec.ts
```

So for rewire I have to provide path of `./dist/controllers/api` and not  `./src/controllers/api`

Here is my sample code:

```
import rewire from "rewire";

const api = rewire('../../dist/controllers/api');   // path to TS build folder

describe("API Controller", () => {
    describe('Fetch Route Params', () => {

        let fetchRouteParams: (url: string) => string;

        beforeEach(() => {
            fetchRouteParams = api.__get__('fetchRouteParams'); // non-exported function
        });

        it('should fetch route params from url', () => {
            const url = "https://example.com/foo/api/products";
            expect(fetchRouteParams(url)).toEqual('foo/api/products');
        });

        it('should not fetch route params from url', () => {
            const url = "";
            expect(fetchRouteParams(url)).toEqual('');
        });
    });
});
```

Even I have not came across some better solution apart from going with `rewire`. But it works for testing non-exported functions.

NPM Packages I have used:

```
npm i -D rewire
npm i -D @types/rewire
```

Hope it helps, Thanks.